# How to let NextJS regenerate static page at a specific time everyday?

Tags: next.js, static-site-generation

I have a NextJS application and a DRF backend. In the NextJS application, I have a `leaderboard` page which pulls data from the DRF backend. However, this `leaderboard` page is updated only once a day.  So, what I'm thinking is I want my NextJS to be able to pull the API once (maybe at 3AM), and generate a static site, so the site would load quickly (as there can be up to 1000 visitors at once so I need the website to be fast). Is this possible? Pardon me I'm very new to NextJS.

Answer (score 1):

You can try "Incremental Static Regeneration" with the new feature "On Demand Revalidation" but it is still in beta! Set up a call from your leaderboard page when it is finished to trigger the new generation of the nextjs page.

See the documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration#on-demand-revalidation-beta